# Is there a proper way to write a path url in django?

Tags: django-urls, django-2.2

I'm using django 2.2 to make a blog project, following an old tutorial (that uses django-1.1) the code goes like this:

```
...    
url(r'^post/new/$', views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name='post_new')
...
```

now in my trial to write the *urlpatterns* using *path* instead of *url* and regular expressions, i translated the code to be:

```
...    
path('post/new/', views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name='post_new')
...
```

and every time i try to run the server it throws the following error at me:

```
Exception Type: ValueError at /post/new/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'new'
```

but accidentally i rewrote the url to be as:

```
...
path('post_new/', views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name='post_new')
...
```

and it worked fine for me!

- so is there a specific way that more recent versions of django accept, which i should stick to in order to name my paths the right way?
- also, what does the error mean?